# Как правильно нарисовать на Jpanel?

Tags: java, netbeans

у меня есть главное окно(MainFrame), где меню, таблица и т.д, и есть свободное место, куда размещено пустой JPANEL(MainDrawPanel), я хочу туда нарисовать фигуры.

У меня есть код, который я уже подготовил, но у меня получается рисовать только в новом окне, JFRAME:

```
    public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
      . . .  
     private void metName () {
     class MyPanel extends JPanel {
                @Override
                protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                    super.paintComponent(g);
                    g.drawString("Contours: " + contours.size(), 20, 20);

                    for (Contour c : contours) {
                        System.out.println(c.getArea());
                        int gg = rnd.nextInt(250);
                        int r = rnd.nextInt(250);
                        int B = rnd.nextInt(250);
                        g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0));

                        ListIterator<Point_dt> itr = c.points.listIterator();
                        Point_dt a = itr.next();//throws Exception if points size = 0

                        while (a != null && itr.hasNext()) {
                            Point_dt b = itr.next();

                            g.drawLine((int) a.x, (int) a.y, (int) b.x, (int) b.y);
                           //g.drawString("(" + a.x + ", " + a.y + ") ", (int)a.x, (int)a.y);
                            //g.drawString("(" + b.x + ", " + b.y + ") ", (int)b.x, (int)b.y);
                            g.fillOval((int) a.x, (int) a.y, 4, 4);
                            g.fillOval((int) b.x, (int) b.y, 4, 4);
                            a = b;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Рисунок");
            JPanel viewer = new MyPanel();

            frame.getContentPane().add(viewer);
            frame.setSize(new Dimension(900, 780));
            frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    . . .
    }
```

Этот код работает, но он рисует на отдельном окне, как мне заставить его работать в главном окне (MainFrame), на пустом JPANEL(mainDrawPanel) ?

Comment: Должно работать и в главном окне. Проверьте лайаут.

Comment: Не обязательно оаследоваться от `JPanel` достаточно от `Component`.

Comment: и потом добавить к панели MainDrawPanel так:

MainDrawPanel.add(viewer); ? 

Так не показывает ничего

Answer (score 0, accepted):

есть подозрение, что вы просто не видите или MainDrawPanel или MyPanel которую вы не нее кладете. Попробуйте так

```
mainDrawPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
mainDrawPanel.add(viewer,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Таким образом всю панель viewer должно растянуть на всю центральную область панели MainDrawPanel. Вот [документация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) по BorderLayout. Так же проверьте размеры MainDrawPanel.

Если я правильно помню, то frame.getContentPane() имеет по умолчанию BorderLayout. А при добавлении без явного указания зоны, элемент добавляется в центр. Поэтому в новом фрэйме у вас все отображается.

Comment: Заработал, как к вашему коду добавил указание размера: 
    `mainDrawPanel.setSize(new Dimension(600, 600));`